# How to solve where an equation where the variable is in the exponent?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

My question is how to solve this problem specifically, but this *type* of problem generally?

$$
2^{n/8} - n < 0
$$

**EDIT**
I should have probably been more specific. This is a computer science algorithms running time question: "For inputs of size $n$, insertion sort runs in $8n^2$ steps, while merge sort runs in $64nlog_2n$ steps. For which values of $n$ does insertion sort beat merge sort?"

So I made this inequality $$8n^2 < 64n\,log_2\,n$$

In the solutions manual they go from $$2^n < n^8$$ to $$2 \leq n \leq  43$$

And I guess I am wondering how they got to there?

So I am not sure if you are just supposed to approximate this with like a graph or if there is a 'simple' way to solve this algebraically?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%28x%2F8%29+-+x+%3D+0+) gives $n \approx 1.099997$ and $n \approx 43.5593$.  This is probably not solvable via elementary functions.  It *is* solvable if you allow a special function, called [Lambert's W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  However, it's not clear what you gain with that solution over the approximate forms unless you have specific need for an analytic solution.

Comment: do you mean to solve it in the integer values of $n$?

Comment: Do you want to find all $n$ (real?  integer?) satisfying this inequality, or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(n)=2^{n/8}-n$$ for which
$$f'(n)=2^{\frac{n}{8}-3} \log (2)-1\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(n)=2^{\frac{n}{8}-6} \log ^2(2)\quad > 0 \quad \forall n$$
The first derivative cancels at
$$n_*=24-\frac{8 \log (\log (2))}{\log (2)}\approx 28.2301$$ This point is a minimum by the second derivative test and
$$f(n_*)=\frac{8 \left(1+\log \left(\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)\right)}{\log (2)}\approx -16.6886$$ So, two roots.

To *approximate* the roots, build a Taylor expansion around $n_*$ to get
$$f(n)=\frac{8 \left(1+\log \left(\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)\right)}{\log (2)}+\frac{\log (2)}{16}  \left(n-n_*\right)^2+O\left(n-n_*)^3\right)$$ This gives two solutions $8.60300$ and $47.8573$.

Now, let us start Newton method with these estimates. The iterates would be

- For the first root

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n_k \\
 0 & 8.6029995 \\
 1 & 0.6563652 \\
 2 & 1.0991250 \\
 3 & 1.0999970
\end{array}
\right)$$

- For the second root

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n_k \\
 0 & 47.857262 \\
 1 & 44.427279 \\
 2 & 43.601473 \\
 3 & 43.559365 \\
 4 & 43.559260
\end{array}
\right)$$

As said in comments, there is explicit solution in terms of Lambet function
$$-\frac{8 W_0\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)}{\log (2)} \qquad \text{and} \qquad -\frac{8 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)}{\log (2)}$$